# Attempt to filter array items that were recently used

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
Array.prototype.spil = function (x,max) {
    if (this.length===max) {
        this.shift();
        this.push(x);
    } else {
        this.push(x);
    }
    return this;
}

var heard = [0],
    freash = [];

$('#speak').bind('touchstart', function() {
    var sounds = [
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
        21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40
    ];
    var temp = sounds;
    for (var i=0; i<heard.length; i++) {
        temp.splice(temp.indexOf(heard[i]), 1);
    }
    freash = temp;
    var say = Math.floor(Math.random() * freash.length+1) + 1;
    heard.spil(say,10);
    say = document.getElementById('c'+say); // audio element
    // use the sound...
});
```

My attempt to make the sound that plays 'an un-recent one' is not working! I want to make the last sound that played not play again for 10 button clicks.

`heard` is the array of sounds that you have already heard, this has a `Array.spil` function which will fill the array via `push` until it reaches its max length of ten when it will `shift` then `push` instead.

`freash` is the array of sounds with no members of the `heard` array present.

You can see that `heard` and `freash` are declared outside of the click (`touchstart`) scope.

If I click/tap over-and-over sometimes I am hearing sounds that have been played already much sooner than I am suppose to, often following each other.

This has been bothering me for days but, I can't see the problem in my logic. Can you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line

```
var say = Math.floor(Math.random() * freash.length+1) + 1;
```

should be

```
var say = freash[Math.floor(Math.random() * freash.length)];
```

Also consider the shortcut

```
var say = freash[Math.random() * freash.length | 0];
```

Comment: ok, +1 for the very nice short cut! **Why that line?, what is wrong there??**

Comment: @8DK The problem with your code is that you use a random key of the array, instead of its corresponding value. For example, say the first time you get `5`, so the next time you will have `[1,...,4,6,...,40]`. But instead of getting one of those numbers, you get a number between `2` and `40`. And the next time, between `2` and `39`, `2` and `38`, and so on. So, instead of preventing recent numbers to be chosen again, you exclude high numbers.